# Non-responsive inline form in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I tried to make my bootstrap site non-responsive following [the official guide](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive), and have some difficulties fighting with inline forms.

The `.form-control` in `.form-inline` will suddenly becomes very long when the screen width is smaller, and push the next element to next line. To me, this is too responsive.

After digging around in css, I noticed it has something to do with the settings in Bootstrap that responses to media query. But I am new to front-end, and don't know what to do to fix it.

Here is a sample, try resizing the browser.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/khBos

Comment: I myself found a way to prevent this by setting `$screen-sm-min: 0px;` in bootstrap scss (I am not a LESS person), and wrote a [blog post](http://ghprince.github.io/2014/09/05/truly-non-responsive-bootstrap-3.html) about it. But I still pick the answer because using css is also a good way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of Bootstrap, and if you take a look at the inline form example in the [Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) and play around with the screen width you'll see the same thing happen.

This is by design since it would be a pretty poor UX to have a bunch of really small inputs all on the same line on a mobile device.  Filling out forms on mobile devices is not easy, so more space is generally better.

However if you want to change this you could add the following to your CSS, which will affect only your `form-groups` within a `form-inline` class:

```
.form-inline .form-group{
    display:inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
```

**[Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/g7WGU4yr9R)**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your styles load AFTER `bootstrap.css` and add this code:

```
.form-group{display:inline-block}
.form-inline .form-control, input, .btn {
    display: inline-block !important;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;

}
```

This way all elements will get the `inline-block` property (you may need to add textarea, select, etc, but it goes up to you and your needs)